# Display over other apps shows itself when debugging

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

When I launch my app on Android, the app launches successfully but it opens the "Display over other apps" settings menu. I can go back to the app through the app switcher, but I don't understand why this is coming up every time. It happens both on the emulator & physical device.

The project **doesn't** need to present its self over other applications.

[Display over other apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMxnJ.png)

Here are my [Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1KXM.png).

Does anyone know why could be happening?

Thanks

**Update**

I'm using code from this project and I think it's causing the issue.
https://github.com/shernandezp/XamarinForms.LocationService

You can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O09Ug.png) that when I run that project, an option does show up for the app to allow or disable the permission. However, it doesn't show up for my project.

I'm not using the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

This is the code that redirects to settings:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M && !Android.Provider.Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        this.StartActivity(intent); // redirect happens when you step over this
    }
```

Comment: You have a foreground service permission, try removing it form your manifest then try

Comment: Also libraries could have their own Manifests that are merged with yours...

Comment: Check the resulting AndroidManifest in obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml and see what it contains. Perhaps some other library is requesting this. It is typically the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` that triggers this. Not `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` as @M.BilalAsif suggests...

Comment: Disabling foreground service doesn't fix the issue. I've checked in my obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml  and there's no `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` in the file.

Comment: why don't you remove the code that redirect to settings ?